# View being cut off (landscape vs. portrait orientation)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, landscape, portrait

I have had this problem countless times and cannot figure out how to fix it.  I am working in an Xcode project (empty project - NO XIB's!). I have my orientation set to landscape:

[image]

But this keeps happening:

[image]

The view is being cutoff.  No matter what I do it doesn't seem to set to the proper size.  For some reason it is displaying the view in landscape using portrait bounds.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  I also want to restrict the orientation to ONLY landscape.

**UPDATE**
The view does not get cutoff if I hard-code 1024 as the width and 768 as the height.  This is obviously a terrible solution, but I cannot figure it out.  Does anyone out there know of a solution?

Comment: Are you using UISplitViewController?

Comment: No. It is just a UIViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer!  One of my friends helped me out with this one.

Views are not oriented until they appear, so, if you are going to add any components to the view and expect them to adhere to an orientation other than the default, which I suspect is portrait, you must add those components in the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`.  I was calling methods that added several components to the view from within the `viewDidLoad` method, however, the view has not appeared, and the orientation not set, when that method is called. Moving my initialization code into the `viewDidAppear` method fixes my problem.

Here is an example:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Probably dont want to draw stuff in here, but if you did, it would adhere to the
    //correct orientation!
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 300);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

    //Call methods from here
    [self initializeScrollView];
    [self addItemToScrollView];
    [self addGraphToView];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the rooViewController that you are setting in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in app delegate class. Make sure you are returning proper allowed orientations in this view controller  class whose object you are setting to rootViewController:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

In your app delegate add this function :

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{ 

 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; 
 }
```

Comment: I added those methods, they didn't do anything.  I assume they are being called automatically?  I called them directly and still nothing changed.

Comment: Also add to the app delegate itself    - (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

Comment: That did not work either.  This bug is killing me.  I didn't realize it was so difficult to set the orientation.

Comment: Sorry buddy, I had faced the same issue and adding these three functions had resolved it. Got no more clues. Just adding the last step to my answer to make it complete. I understand it doesn't help you.

Comment: have you tried putting autoresizing mask in the view you are displaying? something like this: yourView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

Comment: Just added that and it did not work.  This is a very odd bug.  For some reason it thinks it should display it in portrait, even though I specifically set it for landscape only.